# Loading lang files in Laravel depending on prefix/session

Tags: laravel, translation

I build a multilanguage site with 3 languages (**mk** - default, **sq** and **en**) and ended up with the following code in routes.php:

```
$languages = array('en', 'sq');
$locale = Request::segment(1);
if(in_array($locale, $languages)){
    \App::setLocale($locale);
}else{
    $locale = null;
}
// Set the session here
Session::put('locale', $locale);

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController@getIndex'));
    // .... other routes
});
```

My default locale is **'mk'** and I also have 2 other languages in Land folder, **sq** and **en**.
While the routing works fine, problem is when loading lang files. It works for default language **mk** set in app.php and for **en** but won't switch for **sq** translation, and instead it loads the **en** lang files.

Example:

1. URL: http://website.com loads **mk** lang files
2. URL: http://website.com/en loads **en** lang files
3. URL: http://website./sq loads **en** lang files instead of **sq** <--- PROBLEM

Among other code, I have the following in the view:

```
{{{ URL::route('home') }}}
```

The controller is usual:

```
public function getIndex($locale = null)
{

    $data = array();
    return View::make('frontend.frontpage', $data);
}
```

My question: why the **sq** language files aren't loaded when the URI parameter is changed to **sq**?

Comment: Why not using something like this: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: Thanks, that works as expected

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to post that comment as an answer and accept it as the solution to the question? Because it is a legit answer, from my point of view (had the same problem, now using that package).

Comment: @Alomvar how can I do that? I can only vote up the Pat's comment

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for further information. It should be as simple as answering questions everywhere else, simply write an answer on the bottom of the question page. (I would post the answer myself, but that would be stealing reputation from @Pat for actually providing the best solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: **"Loading lang files in Laravel depending on prefix/session"**

@Pat's answer (in comment) solved my issue ([Loading lang files in Laravel depending on prefix/session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549442/loading-lang-files-in-laravel-depending-on-prefix-session#comment30730590_20549442))

In short, using https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization eases creating multilangugage website with Lavarel.